# Using Blade Laravel php template?

Tags: php, templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is it need to use blade foreach like this

```
<!-- Blade foreach -->
@foreach ($users as $user)
 <div class="user">{{ $user->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Because blade PHP template is very similar to C# Razor, is ti possible to use foreach loop like this

```
<!-- Blade foreach -->
@foreach ($users as $user)
 <div class="user">{{ $user->name }}</div>
```

Does I must always end foreach like this @endforeach??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Blade templating does not use indents to recognize the end of controle structures. Behind the scenes it will all be converted to regular PHP. It is just a more convenient and cleaner way to write your views. That is why a `{{ $var }}` outputs the following `<?php echo $var;?>`.

Comment: `{{$var}}` outputs `<?php echo $var;?>`